# how can I give background image to li?

Tags: html, css

The border image is not appearing can anyone help me?

```
#sidebar li {
padding-left: 30px;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #4A3903;
background: url(images/example.PNG) no-repeat 15px 50%;
}
```

Comment: You should add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your html and css.  Your question will be answered much quicker.

Comment: You don't have a border image. Show some more code.

Comment: i've added the url what else do i need??

Comment: This: http://jsfiddle.net/7amqh1e9/

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This: jsfiddle.net/7amqh1e9 –  Sir Celsius

Comment: This: jsfiddle.net/7amqh1e9 –  Sir Celsius i want to use an image of my choice instead of the black dots

Comment: @MaryMelody instead of the black dots i need an image like the logo of my page or something

Comment: @Akshay UPDATED look below...

Comment: @Akshay If that won't solve your problem, then tell me what exactly you want???

Comment: i want to give it a style forget about the border

Comment: @MaryMelody like this http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style-image_crossbrow

Comment: @Akshay LIKE THIS **UPDATED** - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7amqh1e9/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code with - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7amqh1e9/1/)

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar li {
padding-left: 30px;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #4A3903;
background: url(http://www.placehold.it/200x200) no-repeat 15px 50%;
}
```

But the `background-image` is not showing up FULL.

When you add `width` and `height` to your `li` tag equals to your `image`, it will solve the problem.

```
#sidebar li {
padding-left: 80px;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #4A3903;
background: url(http://www.placehold.it/50x50) no-repeat 0px 0px;
width:auto;
height:50px;
list-style:none;
font-size:24px;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
}
```

**UPDATED** - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7amqh1e9/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want background image or border image? For background-image use **background-image** and quote your url:

```
#sidebar li {
   padding-left: 30px; 
   border-bottom: 1px dotted #4A3903; 
   background-image: url('images/example.PNG') no-repeat 15px 50%; 
}
```

For border-image use border-image:

```
 #sidebar li {
        padding-left: 30px; 
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #4A3903; 
        -webkit-border-image:url('border.png') 10 10 round;
        -o-border-image:url('border.png') 10 10 round; 
        border-image:url('border.png') 10 10 round;
     }
```

Comment: i want background image

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
display: block;
```

to your styles as well. (inline-block may also work, if needed)